# Follow The Mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a little question.I have an object that follows the mouse. The problem is that I want when the mouse goes out of the Camera, the object no longer follows.

```
  private Vector3 _target;
public Camera Camera;
public bool FollowMouse;
public bool ShipAccelerates;
public float ShipSpeed = 2.0f;
public float offset = 0.0f;


public void OnEnable()
{
    if (Camera == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Camera not set");
}

public void Update()
{
    if (FollowMouse || Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        _target = Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        _target.z = 0;
    }
    Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
    difference.Normalize();
    float rotation_z = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotation_z + offset);
    var delta = ShipSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    if (ShipAccelerates)
        delta *= Vector3.Distance(transform.position, _target);
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, _target, delta);
 if (Bounds)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, Min_X, Max_X),
                                         Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, Min_y, Max_Y));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check the mouses position before doing your MoveTowards:

```
if(Input.mousePosition.x < YourValueHere || Input.mousePosition.x > YourMinValue || Input.mousePosition.y < YourYValue || Input.mousePosition.y > YMinValue)
{
   transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, _target, delta);
}
```

If you want it to be resolution independent, then I would use a combination of `Screen.Height` and `Screen.Width` for the positive values. 0 will always be your minimum value.

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea, but I do not need it when the mouse leaves the Camera, but when the object comes out of the Camera, Or, more precisely, when the object reaches limits.

Comment: I found the simplest method and modified the script, it works perfectly )))